# How to restrict Resources count in GET request in AzureRM

Tags: rest, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

**How to filter the resources count in GET Request in AzureRM ?**

For an example in  [List Virtual Machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/virtualmachines-list-subscription#request) in an subscription . We get all the Vm's running in an account .

**But I need to get 10 VM's alone in ascending or any sorting order . Is there any filter available like that ?**

Comment: You want  to filter top 10 VM in your subscription?

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT Yes , I need first 10 VM alone .

Comment: Do you try `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/****-****/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualmachines?$top=10&api-version=2016-04-30-preview`?

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT - You should convert your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sorting order does not matter for you, you can filter the resource count for the top 10 VMs in the GET request below:

I've tried the requests below and tweak resource count for filtering and they all worked as expected.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resources?$filter=resourceType eq 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualmachines'&$top=10&api-version={apiVersion}
```

Sample response is like below:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vm}",
            "name": "{vm}",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "location": "{location}"
        },
        {
            "id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vm}",
            "name": "{vm}",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "location": "{location}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks it worked . For people just encode this to UTF-8 in the url . <resourceType eq 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualmachines'>

Comment: @ArunKumarGR, if my answer worked for you, please kindly acknowledge by marking this as answer and helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following API.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/**********/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualmachines?api-version=2017-12-01&top=10
```

Using `$top=10` to filter the top 10 result. See this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#PagingSupport).

Comment: Hi Shengbao, I try your request and it won't even work. I got this error when trying your answer.    {"error":{"code":"InvalidResourceType","message":"The resource type 'virtualMachines' could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.Compute' for api version '201‌​6-04-30-preview'. The supported api-versions are '2015-05-01-preview,2015-06-15,2016-03-30,2016-04-30-preview,2016-08-30,2017-03-30,2017-12-01'."}}

Comment: @juvchan Sorry for my mistake, I update it. When I copy it, a `?` is no need.

Comment: @juvchan You also could test the api in my comment, this is also right. Your error log, it seems some grammatical errors.

Comment: I got this error when I try your updated REST API.                           {"error":{"code":"ProviderError","message":"Resource provider 'Microsoft.Compute' failed to return collection response for type 'virtualMachines'."}}

Comment: @juvchan I am not sure why you get the error log. See my test https://imgur.com/a/tCyWj

Comment: Yes, exact same error message. The HTTP status code is 502. Our REST APIs are also the same expect for the subscription Ids.

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT {  "error": {    "code": "BadRequest",    "message": "The request URL is not valid."  }}

My url : https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualmachines?api-version=2017-12-01&$top=10

Comment: @ArunKumarGR I will check it tomorrow.

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT Thanks ! Don't forget to check .