# How to expand the output of List resources API in AzureRM

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144625/how-to-restrict-resources-count-in-get-request-in-azurerm) I try to list resources using this API ,

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resources?$filter=resourceType eq 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualmachines'&$top=10&api-version={apiVersion}
```

It gives me output like his

```
{
"value": [
    {
        "id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vm}",
        "name": "{vm}",
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
        "location": "{location}"
    },
    {
        "id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vm}",
        "name": "{vm}",
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
        "location": "{location}"
    }
]}
```

I need an expanded Output of each {value} in this call, How to add filter to expand the values ?

can someone throw some spark on this ?

Comment: Based on my knowledge, it is not possible. If you want to get the detailed information about your VM, you need use `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/****/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualmachines?api-version=2017-12-01` to get it.

Comment: I have a idea. Maybe you could get vm's id. And using the id to call API `GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmName}?api-version=2017-12-01` . Using the API to get VM's detailed information.

Comment: In this scenario, maybe you need create a loop. What language you use? API is `https://management.azure.com`+`id`+`?api-version=2017-12-01`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @ShengbaoShui-MSFT .. I was doing like that only but it takes more time. To reduce it only I was asking . 

Can i give top filter in this API ?

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/****/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualmachines?api-version=2017-12-01`

Comment: I test in my lab, it seems this api does not support filter function.

Comment: I test `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/****/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualmachines/?api-version=2017-12-01&top=2` in my lab, but it returns all of my VM.

Comment: its $top is your API correct ?

Comment: This is right. See this screnshot https://imgur.com/a/knAxK

Comment: Then is there any other way to get list of VM details in couple of seconds ?

Comment: Is there anyway we get public IP and private IP in this from this API ? `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/****/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualmachines/?api-version=2017-12-01`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165023/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-arun-kumar-g-r).